# Repeat results query with LEFT JOIN in php MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I try to get data from 3 tables use LEFT JOIN. The problem in one table (image table) when I save images of this topics and as example each topic have 4 images in that table so now when I make query to get those data the results is repeat 4 times in each time all that get from 2 other table repeated but the picture is changing in each query and at the end I get 4 results. How I can solve this problem? I need 4 image but I don't need 4 times query.

As you will see in this is example of my table the topic id 1 have 4 images:

```
table-1 : topic 
+-------+-----------+-----------+-------------------+
|   id  |   name    |    time   |       data        |
+-------+-----------+-----------+-------------------+
|   1   |   John    |     1     |   214-444-1234    |
|   2   |   Mary    |     1     |   555-111-1234    |
|   3   |   Jeff    |     1     |   214-222-1234    |
|   4   |   Bill    |     1     |   817-333-1234    |
|   5   |   Bob     |     1     |   214-555-1234    |
+-------+-----------+-----------+-------------------+
```

```
table-2 : image
+-------+-----------+-----------+-------------+
|   id  |   name    |   image   | Id_Topic    |
+-------+-----------+-----------+-------------+
|   1   |   John    |     png   |   1         |
|   2   |   Mary    |     png   |   1         |
|   3   |   Jeff    |     png   |   1         |
|   4   |   Bill    |     png   |   1         |
|   5   |   Bob     |     png   |   5         |
+-------+-----------+-----------+-------------+
```

```
table-3 : others
+-------+-----------+-----------+-------------------+
|   id  |   name    |   city    |       phone       |
+-------+-----------+-----------+-------------------+
|   1   |   John    |     Uk    |   214-444-1234    |
|   2   |   Mary    |     Uk    |   555-111-1234    |
|   3   |   Jeff    |     Uk    |   214-222-1234    |
|   4   |   Bill    |     Uk    |   817-333-1234    |
|   5   |   Bob     |     Uk    |   214-555-1234    |
+-------+-----------+-----------+-------------------+
```

My query like:

```sql
SELECT * FROM topics
  LEFT JOIN image ON topics.id = image.Id_Topic 
  inner join Others ON topics.id = Others .id
  where topics.id = ?
```

Comment: Please show the exact expected result you want to get for a given topic ID, as a table. Your description is a bit garbled and unclear (probably not helped by it consisting only of one gigantic, unpunctuated, unformatted - and consequently barely-parseable - sentence). There's nothing clearer than a concrete example.

Comment: @ADyson hi bro / I want get one result with 4 image / Images that have a relationship between the topics table and pictures

Comment: Now my query back to me four times of result @ADyson

Comment: Again, as requested, please [edit] your question with a proper example of the expected result for any given inputs. We don't need any further descriptions. Providing an example and rewriting the existing description is a better way. And what makes you assume I'm a "bro"? Not all programmers are male, and in some cultures "bro" is actually a bit of a pejorative term. I'm not offended personally but as a friendly note I'd suggest to refer to people here just by their username so you don't accidentally upset anyone :-)

Comment: @ADyson ok I'm sorry for that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does MySQL [`GROUP_CONCAT`](https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-group_concat/) do what you need?

```
SELECT topic.name, images.images
FROM topic
JOIN (
  SELECT id_Topic, GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT image) images
  FROM image GROUP BY id_Topic
) images ON topic.id = images.id_Topic
;
```

Outputs:

```
| name | images              |
|------|---------------------|
| John | 1png,2png,3png,4png |
| Bob  | 5png                |
```

As you can see, `GROUP_CONCAT` concatenates the several image links using commas, so to display each image you'll need to use your back-end programming language to split the `images` string on comma, then loop the resulting array and present each image individually.

If you have PHP, [`explode()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php)'ing and [looping](https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) may look like this:

```
<?php

// get images string from database: $images_str
// ...

$images_arr = explode($images_str, ',');
foreach ( $images_arr as $image ) {
  echo <<<IMG
    <img src="$image">
IMG;
}

?>
```

Example above, topic name "John", outputs:

```
    <img src="1png">
    <img src="2png">
    <img src="3png">
    <img src="4png">
```

---

```
-- create
CREATE TABLE topic (
  id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
  name TEXT NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE image (
  id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
  id_Topic INTEGER,
  image TEXT NOT NULL,
  name TEXT NOT NULL
);

-- insert
INSERT INTO topic VALUES (1, 'John'), (2, 'Mary'), (3, 'Jeff'), (4, 'Bill'), (5, 'Bob');
INSERT INTO image VALUES (1, 1, '1png', 'John'), (2, 1, '2png', 'Mary'), (3, 1, '3png', 'Jeff'), (4, 1, '4png', 'Bill'), (5, 5, '5png', 'Bob');

-- fetch 
SELECT topic.name, images.images
FROM topic
JOIN (
  SELECT id_Topic, GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT image) images
  FROM image GROUP BY id_Topic
) images ON topic.id = images.id_Topic
;
```

Try it here: https://onecompiler.com/mysql/3yhasjhut

Comment: yes this is what I need but there are one problem in that / the link of image with is id as one link example this is 3 images(ImageTopic: "https://png.pngtree.com/element_our/20200703/ourlarge/pngtree-butterfly-purple-red-wings-ink-transparent-png-bright-image_2300442.jpg,https://www.picng.com/upload/butterfly/png_butterfly_61701.png,https://www.picng.com/upload/butterfly/png_butterfly_61701.pnghttps://www.picng.com/upload/butterfly/png_butterfly_61700.png") what we can do to solve that problem? we cant read image like that it's not work

Comment: see this image please https://d.top4top.io/p_2462dkyon1.png it's coming like this image I can't open it